# How do I catch a JSON parse error when using acceptWithActor with custom types?

Tags: json, scala, websocket, playframework-2.3

I'm using websockets in Play framework 2.3.

Referencing this snippet from [the official how-to page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWebSockets).

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current

def socket = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[InEvent, OutEvent] { request => out =>
  MyWebSocketActor.props(out)
}
```

How would I catch a JSON parse error (RuntimeException: Error parsing JSON)?

This question is very similar to the one linked below, however, I'm using custom types (InEvent, OutEvent) and not the JsValue type.  I don't want to transform to a JsValue or string.  I need it to transform to the InEvent type if successful, or throw a more descriptive error.

[How do I catch json parse error when using acceptWithActor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006968/how-do-i-catch-json-parse-error-when-using-acceptwithactor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere within your scope there are implicit definitions of `FrameFormatter[InEvent]` and `FrameFormatter[OutEvent]`:

```scala
implicit val inEventFrameFormatter = FrameFormatter.jsonFrame[InEvent]
implicit val outEventFrameFormatter = FrameFormatter.jsonFrame[OutEvent]
```

You just have to rewrite both of them, instead of using the predefined [`jsonFrame`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/WebSocket.scala#L84) a custom method like `customJsonFrame`:

```scala
def customJsonFrame[A: Format]: FrameFormatter[A] = 
  FrameFormatter.jsonFrame.transform[A](
    out => Json.toJson(out),
    in => Json.fromJson[A](in).fold(
      error => throw new CustomException(),
      a => a
    )
  )
```

and replace the aforementioned rows with:

```scala
implicit val inEventFrameFormatter = customJsonFrame[InEvent]
implicit val outEventFrameFormatter = customJsonFrame[OutEvent]
```